# Using Auth to get the role of user in a pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following database structure a users & roles table joined using a pivot table:

The users table contains all the info such as email and password, while the roles table defines the different roles :

**roles table**

- 1 -> admin
- 2 -> encoder
- 3 -> salesman
- 4 -> tech

Now the roles are defined many-to-many because, there are some encoders that are assigned also as an admin. Others may have an salesman+admin role, or even encoder+salesman. Basically it multiple roles can be assigned to someone.

### Table Structure

**users**

- id
- email

**roles**

- id
- role

**role_user**

- id
- role_id
- user_id

I know that if I do

```
$user = User::find(1)->email;
return $user;
```

the result would display the email of the user with ID 1.

I was trying to do `$user = Auth::user()->roles;` so that it will get the role of the currently authenticated user.

But doing so returns a JSON which displays all the roles the user is assigned to.

I was hoping to use this in a filter, to do something like this

```
$user=Auth::user()->roles;
if($user == 'admin')
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //you are not an admin
}

if($user == 'encoder')
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //you are not an encoder
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a `many-to-many` relationship so you are getting a collection in the `$user` when you use following code:

```
$user = Auth::user()->roles;
```

So, you need to loop all the `Role` models and have to check `if($someUser->role == 'admin')` within the loop and in this case you may do it like this:

```
$roles = Auth::user()->roles;
$isAdmin = false;
$isAdmin = !$roles->filter(function($role) {
    return $role->role == 'admin';
})->isEmpty();
if($isAdmin) {
    // admin...
}
```

Also you may add a method in your `User` model like this:

```
// User model
public function isAdmin()
{
    $isAdmin = false;
    $isAdmin = !$this->roles->filter(function($item) {
        return $item->role == 'admin';
    })->isEmpty();
    return $isAdmin;
}
```

So you can use:

```
if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
    // admin...
}
```

**Update:** Check any role:

```
public function hasRole($role = null)
{
    $hasRole = false;
    $hasRole = !$this->roles->filter(function($item) {
        return $item->role == $role;
    })->isEmpty();
    return $hasRole;
}
```

Now you can use:

```
if(Auth::user()->hasRole('encoder')) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it also helped me learn that the `Auth::user()` is simply the authenticated user (User model), that is why you can call the `isAdmin()` method. Meaning it is similar to `$user= User::find(1); $user->isAdmin();`

Comment: I tried your code, it worked fine. Until I tried reusing it to check for other roles. And strangely it always return true, even if the authenticated users role is set to encoder. I created `isEncoder()` which checks `if($item->role == 'encoder') return true;` etc.

Comment: There is a mistake in this code: Collection `filter()` always returns a Collection that evaluates to `true` even if it's empty, so `$isAdmin`/`$hasRole` will always be true. You need to check the result if it's empty: `$hasRole = ! $this->roles->filter(...)->isEmpty();` or fetch `role` property of the Roles collection and use `in_array`

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I put the `hasRole()` function in the User model, but whenever I try it, like testing it on a route, it gives an error `Undefined variable: role` which point to this line of code `return $item->role == $role;`

Comment: The hasRole is perfect. The other one was giving unexpected results. It did not validate the role and was letting the user continue.

Answer (score 4):

Just a small fix for the code at the bottom:

```
public function hasRole($role = null) {
    $hasRole = false;
    $hasRole = !$this->roles->filter(function($item) use ($role) {
        return $item->name == $role;
    })->isEmpty();
    return $hasRole;
}
```

@lozadaOmr: You have to add "use"!