# users roles access to specific menus

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles

I have an laravel 4 application and I want to add some users roles "admin" and "operator". Admin should have some proviledges to use some additional menus than operator. I have this header.blade.php which has the header menu.

```
<div class="media user-media">
    <div class="user-media-toggleHover">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- #menu -->
<ul id="menu" class="">
    <li class="">
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
            <span class="link-title">
                {{Lang::get('messages.history')}}
            </span> 
            <span class="fa arrow"></span> 
        </a> 
        <ul>
            <li class="">
                {{ Helpers\Helper::fa_link_to_action('glyphicon glyphicon-time','CarController@history',Lang::get('messages.update_history'),null,array(
                            'class'=>'link-title'))
                }}
            </li>   
            <li class="">
                {{ Helpers\Helper::fa_link_to_action('glyphicon glyphicon-time','CarController@insert_history',Lang::get('messages.insert_history'),null,array(
                            'class'=>'link-title'))
                }}
            </li>  
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            <span class="link-title">
                Menu3
            </span> 
            <span class="fa arrow"></span> 
        </a> 
        <ul>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;Submenu1</a> 
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;Submenu2</a> 
            </li>             
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul><!-- /#menu -->
```

Than this is included at layout>default.blade.php

```
 <head>
        @include('includes.header')
    </head>
```

default.blade.php is included in all view pages. Now I want for example that settings menu to be displayed only to admin. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably try something along like this

```
@if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin')
    {{-- stuff for the admin --}}
@endif
```

---

**Update**

First of you can store the roles using a pivot table, where the use_id, and role_id will be stored.

Then you can refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23546770/1679011) in this question, when you want to check the role a user has.

Comment: this way one users will have only one role? because you are saying to save role_id at users table?

Comment: Well you could try saving the roles in pivot table, so that a user can have multiple role. Also, you can add a method on the user model, which checks the type of role/s a user has.